# Not sure why my function keeps returning an error?

Tags: c

Writing a function that returns the last occurrence of the character. It returns a pointer pointing to the last matching character, or null if no match was found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

char* my_strrchr(char* a, char b) {

    if(a == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char i;
    i=0;
    while(a[i] != '\0') {
        a[i] = b;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return a;

}

int main(void) {
    char a[] = "abc";
    char b = 'c';

    printf("%s\n", my_strrchr("abc", b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You're trying to change characters in a string literal though, which I don't think works.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `a` in main is a char array, not a string literal

Comment: @M.M You never use `a` in `main `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Writing a function that returns the last occurrence of the character. It returns a pointer pointing to the last matching character, or null if no match was found.

But that is not what your function `my_strrchr` does. The function assigns the value in `b` to each character before `\0` (assuming `a` needs to point to a string) and thereafter returns a pointer to the first element of the array `a` is pointing to regardless of where the last occurrence of the provided character in `b` in the string is:

```
while(a[i] != '\0') {
    a[i] = b;
    i = i + 1;
}

return a;
```

What your need is more something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* my_strrchr(char* a, char b) {

    if(a == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t len = strlen(a);

    for(size_t i = len; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(a[i-1] == b)
        {
            return &a[i-1];
        } 
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char a[] = "abc";
    char b = 'c';

    printf("%s\n", my_strrchr("abc", b));

    return 0;
}
```